# Using Terraform to Enable Microsoft Defender for Storage on a Storage Account to scan for Malware

Tags: azure, terraform, malware, azure-storage-account, windows-defender

Im trying to enable malware scanning using "Microsoft Defender for Storage" on a Storage Account using terraform, but im not able to find out how to do it. Is it not supported in Terraform? Im trying to enable the "On-upload malware scanning" option on the "Microsoft Defender For Cloud". Are there any other means of programatically doing this (if its not yet supported in Terraform)?
[image]

Comment: Refer to this Microsoft article: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-defender-for-cloud/deploy-microsoft-defender-for-cloud-via-terraform/ba-p/3563710

By @Liana_Tomescu Once

Comment: Enabling malware scanning using "Microsoft Defender for Storage" on a Storage Account is currently not supported directly in Terraform. The Terraform provider for Azure does not have a specific resource for configuring this feature.
However, you can still enable "On-upload malware scanning" on the "Microsoft Defender for Cloud" using Terraform by leveraging the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template deployment feature in Terraform. This allows you to deploy ARM templates that include the configuration for enabling the malware scanning feature.

Comment: Im not see any means of setting it at the Resource level (a specefic storage account). They are all showing samples for setting at the Subscription level

Answer (score 2):

This has been added in a recent version of azurerm for terraform. (Specifically in 3.76.0)
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/security_center_storage_defender

```
resource "azurerm_security_center_storage_defender" "example" {
  storage_account_id = module.example.id
  
  override_subscription_settings_enabled      = true   # Optional
  sensitive_data_discovery_enabled            = true   # Optional
  malware_scanning_on_upload_enabled          = true
  malware_scanning_on_upload_cap_gb_per_month = -1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I resolved it using ARM template. In the resource definition, the "template_body" reference the template body file "malware-scan-configuration.json"

```
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "malware" {
  name                = "${module.app_service.default_site_hostname}.Scan"
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group.name
  template_body       = file("templates/malware-scan-configuration.json")

  parameters = {
    storage_account_name = my_storage_storage_account_name
    subscription_id      = my_subscription_id
    resource_group       = my_resource_group_name
    event_grid_topicName = my_event_grid_topic_name
    cap_gb_per_month     = 5000
  }
  deployment_mode = "Incremental"
  depends_on = [
  ]
}
```

template body file: **malware-scan-configuration.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storage_account_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "subscription_id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "resource_group": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "event_grid_topicName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "cap_gb_per_month": {
      "type": "int"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Security/DefenderForStorageSettings",
      "apiVersion": "2022-12-01-preview",
      "name": "current",
      "properties": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "malwareScanning": {
          "onUpload": {
            "isEnabled": true,
            "capGBPerMonth": "[parameters('cap_gb_per_month')]"
          },
          "scanResultsEventGridTopicResourceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscription_id'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('resource_group'), '/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/', parameters('event_grid_topicName'))]"
        },
        "sensitiveDataDiscovery": {
          "isEnabled": false
        },
        "overrideSubscriptionLevelSettings": true
      },
      "scope": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storage_account_name'))]"
    }
  ],

  "outputs": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (azapi provider needed):

```
resource "azapi_resource" "defender_settings" {
  name = "current"
  type = "Microsoft.Security/DefenderForStorageSettings@2022-12-01-preview"
  parent_id = azurerm_storage_account.netflowstorage.id
  schema_validation_enabled = false
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      isEnabled = false
      malwareScanning = {
        onUpload = {
          isEnabled = false
          capGBPerMonth = 5000
        }
      }
      sensitiveDataDiscovery = {
        isEnabled = false
      }
      overrideSubscriptionLevelSettings = true
    }
  })
}
```

Note: you may need to tweak it to be an update_resource (put operation) if you've already got settings defined on the resource (tf will tell you the resource already exists and needs importing):

```
resource "azapi_update_resource" "defender_settings" {
  name = "current"
  type = "Microsoft.Security/DefenderForStorageSettings@2022-12-01-preview"
  parent_id = azurerm_storage_account.netflowstorage.id
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      isEnabled = false
      malwareScanning = {
        onUpload = {
          isEnabled = false
          capGBPerMonth = 5000
        }
      }
      sensitiveDataDiscovery = {
        isEnabled = false
      }
      overrideSubscriptionLevelSettings = true
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add this at the subscription level for all future storage accounts with terraform ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-storage-infrastructure-as-code-enablement?tabs=enable-subscription)):

```
resource "azurerm_security_center_subscription_pricing" "mdc_storage" {
  tier          = "Standard"
  resource_type = "StorageAccounts"
  subplan       = "DefenderForStorageV2"

  extension {
    name    = "OnUploadMalwareScanning"
    additional_extension_properties  = {
      CapGBPerMonthPerStorageAccount = 100
    }
  }

  extension {
    name = "SensitiveDataDiscovery"
  }

}
```

You can use @addstar's answer to adjust the configuration per storage account